# Stopping Bot [SO] - PHP

Tags: php, security, captcha, verification

I saved this code in index.php and after filling i clicked Submit button, and then a verification page was shown to me !
My question is **how did it detected that it was not from the original server** ?
*[i hope they do not use the referrer as it can be disabled easily]*

My Fake Code

```
<html>
 <form id="post-form" action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit" method="post">
  <input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" class="ask-title-field" value="">                        
  <textarea id="wmd-input" name="post-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101"></textarea>
  <input id="tagnames" name="tagnames" type="text" size="60" value="" tabindex="103">
  <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Question" tabindex="120">  
 </form>
</html>
```

**Can anyone guide me creating such secure page** *[where if a user tries to post from a dull page, he will be asked for verification]* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Generate a token on the server.
2. Put that token into a hidden input element.
3. Save that token on the server in a list of generated forms.
4. When a form submission comes in

   1. check whether the token was passed and is valid,
   2. remove the token from the list of generated forms.

I suspect that this is what `<input id="fkey" type="hidden" value="..." name="fkey">` on the question submission form is for.

Comment: If you save the token in the database. You can also save the token in the session. Furthermore, the additional operations are only needed on form submissions, i.e. requests that already make heavy use of the database (due to INSERT and UPDATE operations). The additional database operations in that case are probably negligible.

Comment: so what should i use as the token ? something like   **sha1(uniqid().$salt)** ?

Comment: @Sourav use memory to store token.

Comment: @Sourav Use some randomness. If the user wants to know which one you used, he just needs to download a current version of the form. It's a good idea to know which user downloaded a form, so only that user can submit it using the token. It's also a good idea to keep a list of valid tokens, so the user can open multiple tabs in his browser. Also, form submissions that do not trigger manipulation of entity objects might not need such security (e.g. the search form has no hidden form element). In the way outlined by @bobince, the actual value of the token is more important.

Answer (score 2):

> good idea, but it puts pressure on the DB too :(

You can create an anti-XSRF token without the element of having to remember them all on the server.

You can do this by putting the information you want to verify inside the token, typically including:

- user ID, so one user can't create a form that submits for another user
- an expiry timestamp, so that tokens don't last forever

then hash this information together with a secret key and spit it out in the hidden field. When the token comes back in, you can look at the information given, hash it with the key again and see if the hash matches the user's submission.

So for example, for user ID 18936 with expiry timestamp 1304861680 (Unix time for about now), you could create a token like:

```
18936.1304861680.2A956E39.11E859E44B9308B812257BEE660330D9D0566189
```

where 2A956E39 is some random salt, and the bit at the end is the hex-encoded HMAC-SHA1 hash of `18936.1304861680.2A956E39` using the not-very-good secret key `secretkey`.

This achieves the anti-XSRF purpose, but sometimes the one-time-server-stored-token is also used to prevent a form double-submission. As-is, the hash method doesn't help with that bit. But in the specific case of creating a new entity, which is a common place double-submission-prevention is deployed, you can use the token as a unique value inserted into the DB as part of the new entity, and then refuse to create a new entity if there's already one with the token in it.

Comment: If token being generated from some public data, he can be generated by 'other user' too. Protection, based on lucky chance it's not protection.

Comment: @OZ_: without the server's secret key you cannot create a token that will be accepted by the server. By putting a user identifier in the signed part of the token, there is no way one user can generate a token for another user. Just guessing a key would give you a working result one time in 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 (or more if you used a longer hash like SHA-256), which would be a lucky chance indeed...

Comment: `there is no way one user can generate a token for another user` - if ID is public information (and user's ID it's almost always are public information), then another user can generate token for another user, just by using his ID in algorithm. With hash of private data (such as password) this token can be generated. Then, if another user doesn't know password, he will not be able to generate token. And when he know password... tokens already not necessary :)

Comment: That is why the secret key is called ‘secret’! It is not divulged to any user and always stays exclusively on the server. It is not the user's password.

Comment: @bobince yes, if key is not divulged to any user - then yes, I agree with this method.