# Response when requested by the Original code - PHP

Tags: php, security

As proposed by [Stopping Bot [SO] - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927614/stopping-bot-so-php) i've developed a anti-bot system in PHP which code can be viewed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/anti-bot-comment-system-php

But anyone can obtain a token by viewing `getToken.php`
In SO they get the token from `stackauth.com` [i think so by viewing page code], but when i browsed it it just showed some text !
How can i do something like that ? [token to be passed only when requested by the code, not by the browser]

The process of generating and verifying token
in the form page

```
$hash=sha1($time.$myKey);
echo $time.'#'.$hash;
```

In the poster/verification page

```
$token=explode($_POST['token'],'#',2);
if (sha1($token[0].$myKey)==$token[1])
 echo 'A good Human';
```

`Edit`
I do not store used token in the database, and a token get expired after [say] 5 minutes !
Think a bad user gets the token **2011-05-18 11:10:12#AhAShKey000000000**  he can use the token to submit random text to **2011-05-18 11:15:12**, how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Before putting down or close vote plz explain the reason !

Comment: I can not use CAPTCHA all the, as this will force the user to hate the site !

Comment: Checking HTTP_REFERER or such option is not an answer coz they can be changed easily !

Comment: It sounds like you want a way to check that a real human requested the token without the human having to do anything. There just is no such scheme. The best you can do is make it slightly harder to spam your site by checking the user agent, referrer, etc.

Comment: but now a days it's really possible for a layman to change those things :( have you tried SO's token system ? try it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the answer carefully i've developed this [thanx to all the people for their valuable comment and answer]

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
for ($i=1;$i<=10000;$i++)
 generateMath();

echo 'Generating '.$i.' math Took '.(microtime()-$time);

function generateMath()
{
 $operands = array(43,45,42);
 $val = chr(rand(48,57));
 $ope = chr($operands[rand(0,2)]);
 $txt = $val.$ope; //42* 43+ 45- 47/
 $val2 = chr(rand(48,57));
 $txt .= $val2;
 $ans = 0;
 if ($ope == '+')
  $ans = $val + $val2;
 else if ($ope == '-')
  $ans = $val - $val2;
 else if ($ope == '*')
  $ans = $val * $val2;
 echo $txt.' -> '.$ans.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

This can be enhanced by adding random number of spaces in   `$txt = $val.$spaces.$ope.$spaces.$val2;`

And it was faster than CAPCHA, people will have to do a really simple math if they post more than 30 or so comments in an hour !

Comment: i avoided division as it generates sometime division by zero

Answer (score 3):

Not *totally* sure this is the answer you're after, but...

Load the token statically in the page, instead of with Ajax.  Then you know that the form page was loaded for sure.

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but the problem is **any one can make a bot which downloads a form and then extract the token [by doing some simple search] and use it to submit spam/data, how to stop that ?**

Comment: Well, a human could spam it too (manually).  If you want to keep out automated spamming, use a captcha, or an [alternative](http://www.google.com/search?q=captcha+alternative).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ftok(__FILE__,'T');` - and token will be unique on each system.
Instead of `T` you can use any letter, read [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftok.php).

As example, in your getToken.php you can replace:
`$hash=sha1($key.'mySecretKey');`
with
`$hash=sha1($key.ftok(__FILE__,'T'))`;

This function exists only in linux/unix-based systems.

Answer (score 1):

That won't stop anything, in fact it'll only add more strain on your server.

Use [hashcash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683117/alternative-to-annoying-captcha-in-forms-how-to-smell-the-difference-between-a-h/4774229#4774229) instead ([Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-hashcash/)).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is going to completely stop this kind of activity. For the 99.99999999999% case though, a method that uses a server side component plus something that uses *javascript* to do a transform on the the data you get back from the server is going to stop the majority of bots that are out there (unless they're based on node.js and are using jsdom ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is kind of impossible to fix. You can't see if a bot or a browser is viewing your "token page". All things you could check for are also possible to mimic. (Referrers, more hashes or user-agents)

You should ask yourself, what do you want to protect your site from? For a regular bot you methods is okay, it will take way too much time to crack your script and spam just your site. It will just go on and spam someone else. So in that cast your script will give enough protection.

When there is someone targeting just your site and he takes the time to crack it, he will probably succeed. So you also want to keep this kind of bots/people out? I would suggest to display a captcha after, for example, 3 posts within an hour from one IP-address. That will keep them out.

It's not always about being completely secure, your solution could already be good enough... If more protection is required, just use captchas or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this, as is everything else, is not completely secure.

You could try creating a similar hash with javascript that carries the time and a unique ID of the user and sending that with the request. 
You can then even add that to the code generation and verification. 
In the absence of this hash, no code is served.

Sort of like a handshake.